# ASP.NET MVC Forcing Page Redirect After 5 Minutes (Different Pages)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building a gallery website that allows visitors to view different photographs. I want to require visitors to register once they spend more than 5 minutes on the website. This includes **page redirections**. So, I am trying to come up with a way to redirect visitors to my registration page and disallow any further photography viewing until they make an account.

JS code like the following only keeps track of the currently active page:

```
var delay = 1000; 
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = URL; }, delay);
```

Is there any way to keep track of the visitor's overall time-spent? And force a page redirection if the time exceeds 5 minutes?

Any guidance will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: how about using sessions?

Comment: Seems like storing a cookie with the time of initial visit (from JavaScript) would be a good solution. You can then do some math to work out if it has been longer than 5 min. Using [session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/) for something like this seems like overkill.

Comment: Use HTML5 session storage, window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser is closed).

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setTimeout(window.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in",300000 );
```

Use the above code in page load or in window load.(5min=300000ms)